# "make" command for rcssmonitor project

Tags: c++

I'm installing rcssmonitor for soccer2d sim and there is a problem in making this project, here's the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfontconfig
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:477: recipe for target 'rcssmonitor' failed
make[2]: *** [rcssmonitor] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/rccserver/rcssmonitor/src'
Makefile:382: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/rccserver/rcssmonitor'
Makefile:322: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I downloaded the latest version from sourceforge
how can I fix it?

Comment: You need to install `fontconfig` library. `apt install fontconfig` for ubuntu, your-distro's-package-manager for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a fresh enough Debian/Ubuntu the required package is called `libfontconfig1-dev`. Perform `apt install libfontconfig1-dev` (almost) as @krzaq suggested.

But likely you will need other development packages as well. If linker blames on `-lsome`, then you need a shared library `libsome.so`, usually located in `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib32` (there could be other variations like `/lib`, `/usr/lib64` etc). Perhaps the easiest way to understand what package a given file belongs to is to install [apt-file](https://wiki.debian.org/apt-file) package and then to query required libraries.